# Kendo Grid with Locked Columns splits to next line

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a kendo grid with many columns.  The grid width is 100%  The first too columns are locked.  After my ajax call where I get/set the grid data, the right hand side of the grid is displaying below the left hand side of the grid.  It has something to do with how the internal sizing calculation is done.  If the grid is given a specific width, the issue doesn't show up.  This is unsatisfactory however because the grid then does not display the same way in different browser and does not resize like it does when the width is 100%.

Has anyone else seen this or know how to prevent it?

Please see the image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All Grid column's widths need to be explicitly specified in pixels for the locked column functionality to work as expected:

[LINK TO DOCS](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/#toc-locked-state)

Once this requirement is met, you can set the width of the Grid to be 100%, and the Grid will still be displayed as expected:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="370" style="width: 100%">
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="50" [locked]="true">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250" [locked]="true">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Category.CategoryName" title="Category" width="200">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="280">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="280">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" title="Discontinued" width="220">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued" disabled/>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3kmOf54DT7JUG68qUdaP?p=preview